# Can I insert a node before current node in singly linked list using C?

Tags: c, data-structures

Is this even possible, because singly linked list does not have pointer to previous, only next? I have a task to do where I have to write a function that inserts a node before current node, and I just can't seem to do it.

EDIT: I made this

```
    void before(List* list, int value) {
        Node * temp = new_node(value);
        temp->data = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
    if(list->size == 0){
        temp->next = list->current;
        list->current = temp;
        return;
    }else{
    for(Node * p = list->head->next; p == list->current; p = p->next){
        list->head = list->current;
        list->current =  list->current->next;
    }
 temp->next = list->head->next;
 list->head->next = temp;
    }
}
```

But for input

```
    insert_after_current(list, 1);
    insert_after_current(list, 2);
    insert_after_current(list, 3);
    insert_after_current(list, 4);
    before(list, 5);
```

I receive output

```
1 5 2 3 4
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and there are tons of examples out there proving it.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't find any. There is tons of examples that show how to insert at specific position, at the end, beginning, but not current. I had many ideas but I don't know how, none of them worked. I'll try what dbush wrote.

Comment: Found this. Does it help? https://qnaplus.com/insert-element-singly-linked-list/

Comment: Not so sure. I edited my post with some code I managed to create.

Answer (score 1):

As you traverse the list, you need to keep track of the previous node you visited.

Once you find the node you want to insert before, have the previous node point to the new node and have the new node point to the current node.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I thought, for some reason, that I wasn't allowed to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *insert(node *parent, node *newnode)
{
    if(parent && newnode)
    {
        newnode -> next = parent -> next;
        parent -> next = newnode;
    }
}

node *insertbefore(node **haystack, node *needle, node *newnode)
{
    node *parent = *haystack;

    if(needle == *haystack)
    {
        newnode -> next = *haystack;
        *haystack = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(parent -> next)
        {
            if(parent -> next == newnode)
            {
                insert(parent, newnode);
            }
            else
            {
                newnode = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return newnode;
}
```